# Gnome Network-Manager OpenVPN

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, networkmanager, openvpn

I cannot get OpenVPN to work with GNOME NetworkManager.

Authentication-Type is "Certificates (TLS)"

I have 3 files:

- UserCert: user.crt
- CACert: ca.key
- PrivateKey: user.key

All live in my home-directory.
Connection fails with the following message:

```
Feb 25 23:16:49 archpad nm-openvpn[1138]: OpenVPN 2.3.2 x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6
Feb 25 23:16:49 archpad nm-openvpn[1138]: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.n
Feb 25 23:16:49 archpad nm-openvpn[1138]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defi
Feb 25 23:16:49 archpad nm-openvpn[1138]: WARNING: file '/home/mak/Downloads/user.key' is group or others accessible
Feb 25 23:16:49 archpad nm-openvpn[1138]: Cannot load CA certificate file /home/mak/Downloads/ca.key (OpenSSL)
Feb 25 23:16:49 archpad nm-openvpn[1138]: Exiting due to fatal error
Feb 25 23:16:49 archpad NetworkManager[422]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Feb 25 23:16:49 archpad NetworkManager[422]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Feb 25 23:16:49 archpad NetworkManager[422]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Feb 25 23:16:49 archpad NetworkManager[422]: <info> Policy set 'tb303' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Feb 25 23:16:49 archpad NetworkManager[422]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection
```

**UPDATE**

Output of

```
openssl x509 -in  /home/mak/Downloads/ca.key -noout -text
```

is

```
unable to load certificate
140493069354640:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is the fatal error:

```
Cannot load CA certificate file /home/mak/Downloads/ca.key
```

There are a couple reasons that it may not be able to load the key:

1. Permissions are wrong. Check to make sure the file is readable
2. File doesn't exist. Confirm the path & name is correct.
3. File is in the wrong format, or is not a CA certificate. Try `openssl x509 -in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/MetricsCA.crt -noout -text` Make sure it spits out something starting 'Certificate:', that the current date/time is inside the validity, and that it has 'CA:TRUE' as one of the basic constraints.

Comment: updated my answer with the output of openssl, seems there´s something wrong with my cert?!?

Comment: @sine Yep. If you look at the certificate file (its plain text) it should start with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`, or at least have a line reading that. I suspect yours doesn't.